# Is there a conventional, widely used icon for decision support?

Tags: icon, interface-design, user-experience

I did some research to figure out what icons exist for decision support, and which of those represents the decision support the best. I didn't find any suitable icons, because I think they don't represent the "support" aspect, and are not widely used: the user can not understand what the icon means.

These two seem to be useful:

[image: DSS icon 1] [image: DSS icon 2]

But both are too complex for me, and don't represent the workflow decision, like this:
[image: workflow icon 1]

But the last one is also not understandable for a regular user.

Does anyone have a good idea for a decision support icon? My goal is to represent that a software helps to classify incoming measured data, make a decision and track the decision's consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Azendh, if I might make a suggestion. Head over to [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com) and ask them for help with finding a more concise word for "classify incoming measured data and make a decision and follow-up the decision's consequences."

My initial reaction is that what you seem to describe is: User inputs data with a and produced result is a function. f(x) is one possible solution. One of the most common ways to portray that is with the following image:

[image]

Perhaps you, or your designer, could create a stylized and simplified version of that.

Another thing that comes to my mind when reading your description is [WHAT-IF Analysis](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introduction-to-what-if-analysis-HA010243164.aspx). It's icon within Excel looks like this:

[image]

Which you might notice is a simplified version of a function box. Two inputs in and something gets questioned producing a result.

Only other word that comes to mind is [Forecast](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/forecast-HP005209096.aspx). This was an interesting icon that came up for Forecast but is a little lacking the idea of user input:

[image]

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The last one gives me some inspiration, but I still not have the best representation.

Answer (score 0):

I like using spanner/wrench icons for generic 'Support' branding, it makes a lot of sense for most users (who would probably be contacting support to 'fix' something).

It's definitely worth having a look on [IconFinder](https://www.iconfinder.com/), if you can't find an icon you like you should be able to get some inspiration at least!

Comment: The spenner/wrench means settings for me, and also not contains the support. Thanks for the iconfinder link, but I still can't find suitable, already.

Comment: That's interesting - for me (and [and IconFinder too](https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=settings) apparently) Settings is best represented as a Cog. Some spanners in there too though!

Comment: I maybe too old... spenner/wrenchs icons are used as settings in '90-s widely. As far as I remember :)